# Some children are from (broken families / a broken family)

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I’m always confused on how to make sentences that have plural subjects and they belong to a group.

I want to make a general statement that "**some children** are from **a broken family**" but I’m not sure whether to use ***a family*** or ***families*** as they are not coming from same family.

Comment: If you use the singular it might seem as though all the children are from a single family. It is unusual for a child to belong to more than one family, so if you use the plural the meaning is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Not coming from the same family, I would say:

> Some children are from broken families.

If they were from the same family, I would say:

> The children are from a broken family.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you say *some children* it is often interpreted as meaning children in general—not specific children. Also, without further clarification, it's not clear if you're actually talking about one or more broken families when it comes to a specific child.

To avoid any misinterpretation, you have to be very explicit.

**(1)** Talking about each single child in a group, who has been on their own:

> Each child is from different multiple broken families.
>   Each child is from a different single broken family.

**(2)** Talking about all of the children in a small group, who have, together, been placed with families:

> All the children are from the same multiple broken families.
>   All the children are from the same single broken family.

**(3)** If you don't care about being so specific, and it doesn't matter if some children in a group grew up with others or on their own, but you still want to indicate just one family or several families:

> Some children are from multiple broken families.
>   Some children are from a single broken family.

**(4)** Finally, the most general statement, where it doesn't matter if children in a group were paired with others or not, or how many families they grew up in (or even if you're not talking about a specific group at all), then you can fall back to your general statements. And, with those, it doesn't matter *which* statement you use:

> Some children are from broken families.
>   Some children are from a broken family.

Both of these last statements could be interpreted to mean anything.